# How to get inventory items from a PayPal API?

Tags: paypal

I'm building inventory management software for Square and PayPal. After reviewing PayPal's RESTful API documentation, its not clear how I can retrieve inventory items from a merchant on their behalf.

For example, before a transaction is made or an invoice is created, I'd like to get their inventory items to beging improving the inventory management experience.

**Does anyone know how I can retrieve inventory items from a PayPal API?**

Thanks in advance - Royce

Answer (score 0):

PayPal doesn't provide an inventory management system/service for merchants. The item list you see in the Restful API, is how a merchant can indicate what items the buyer is purchasing so PayPal can display that on the Payment confirmation page. If you are talking about how to obtain that information then you can do a GET on the payment resource id, which will include the items info that was originally provided by the merchant.

Comment: my question is which PayPal API do I use to retrieve items (i.e., products) added to the PayPal Here iPad app?